# conditional aws iam policies / bucket policies in requester tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, permissions, amazon-iam

**TLDR**: what's the way filtering iam policies in aws by requests tags.

**Scenario:** I have some groups of **production servers that implements the same iam role** named `production`:

- `instance_a` implements iam_role `production` and contains tags `group_name:backend`
- `instance_b` implements iam_role `production` and contains tags `group_name:backend`
- `instance_c` implements iam_role `production` and contains tags `group_name:client`
- `instance_d` implements iam_role `production` and contains tags `group_name:client`

In addition, I have a s3 bucket named `secret_bucket` which needed to be restricted In permission and opened only to ec2 instances with `backend` tag name.

**Problem:** When I create a specific s3 bucket policy to production role **I'm having issues to filter the request condition** ( aka all the ec2 instances with `group_name:backend`) because the conditional statements in aws iam policies dedicated to resource attributes (s3) and not on the requester attributes (ec2) , I can filter all the tag names of the s3 bucket itself but need the aws instances that access the db ).

**clarification**: the straight forward solution would be assigning this policy to production iam role though the client and backend share the same iam role `production` and client instances are restricted.

This policy would be implemented in terraform, attaching my bucket policy
What's the best approach for dealing with this issue?

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "aws_s3_bucket_resource_based_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.secret_bucket.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Id      = "allow_backend_access_id_policy"
    Statement = [
      {
        Sid       = "allow_backend_access"
        Effect    = "Allow"
        "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "123456789"
        ]
       },
        Action    = ["s3:*"]
        Resource = [
          aws_s3_bucket.secret_bucket.arn,
          "${aws_s3_bucket.secret_bucket.arn}/*",
        ]
        Condition = {
          StringEquals = {
            "aws:ResourceTag/group_name" = "backend"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried this, but should you be using `aws:RequestTag/${TagKey}` to identify the requester (EC2)? I'd personally prefer to assign distinct IAM roles to the relevant server types and provide the appropriate level of S3 access in that IAM role.

Comment: aws:RequestTag/${TagKey} not working

Comment: Where did you read/find that EC2 instance tags are propagated to IAM requests originating from the instance?

Comment: This looks like a lot of work to avoid assigning client and backend different roles